# Parsing Garbage Values Randomly Arrays

Tags: arrays, random, multidimensional-array

I am generating random values and parsing into arrays.
Any idea which part is causing the problem?

Thank you all in advance! :)

```
for(x=0; x<numberOfSboxes; x++)
{
    vecCheck.clear();
    for (y=0;y<sbox_Size; y++)
    {       
        int secondTemp = y;
        int firstTemp;
        firstTemp = rand() % numberRange;

        int mycount = (int) std::count (vecCheck.begin(), vecCheck.end(), y); // count if number is in vector
        if( (mycount==1) || (firstTemp==y)  )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if(vecCheck.size()==0)
            {
                vecCheck.push_back(firstTemp); // first number
                sBox[x][y] = firstTemp;
                sBox[x][firstTemp] = secondTemp;
                vecCheck.push_back(secondTemp); //second number 
            }
            else
            {                   
                int mycount = (int) std::count (vecCheck.begin(), vecCheck.end(), firstTemp); // count if number is in vector
                if(mycount==1)
                {
                    //if number generated is found, then break loop and restart
                    --y;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if number generated is not found
                    sBox[x][y] = firstTemp; // first number generated
                    sBox[x][firstTemp] = secondTemp;
                    vecCheck.push_back(firstTemp); //push back to record
                    vecCheck.push_back(secondTemp); //push back to record
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does not always generate garbage values but sometimes it does.
An example is to be shown below.

```
  sBox[0][16] = {9,12,15,5,7,3,12765952,4,13,0,11,10,1,8,12688216,2};
  sBox[1][16] = {6,11,3,2,8,10,0,15,4,134514593,5,1,14,-1075,0,78827,12,7};
  sBox[2][16] = {3,4,7,0,1,13,11,2,10,14,8,6,15,5,9,12};
```

I do not think it has a problem on the rand().

EDIT:

firstTemp generation has no issues. the numbers are always in the range of 0-15.
anyone knows why the output of the values tend to be of such stated above?

Comment: For one thing - using `std::find` would be more efficient than `std::count`, because it stops after the first element (presumably this is behaviour you want).

Comment: What's `sbox_Size` and what's `numberRange`?

Comment: @Dukeling - My sbox_Size is 16. and my numberRange is 15.

Comment: Maybe those values were set before? Try initializing `sBox` as a new array before you run this code.

Comment: @Salman - thank you Salman it worked! By initialising values to the sBox works!